# ReferenceError: $ is not defined while using Angular Universal

Tags: angular-universal

I'm using jquery in angular and it's working but when i have added angular universal i got this error.

**angular.json**

```
        [
          "src/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-ui.js"
       ]
```

**App.component.ts**

```
       declare var $: any;
```